# how to use Logstash to rename files in aws s3

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, logstash

I want to use Logstash to rename incoming files.

Example:

- incoming file is saved as /customer1/file.txt
- Logstash renames the file to /customer1/date/file.txt
- incoming file is saved as /customer2/file.txt
- Logstash renames the file to /customer2/date/file.txt

Iam i right with my assumption that i don't need elastic search for that?

Currently iam running Logstash locally in docker and have the following configuration:

```
    input {
  s3 {
    access_key_id => "something"
    secret_access_key => "something_else"
    region => "some_region"
    bucket => "mybucket"
    interval => "10"
    backup_add_prefix =>'s3://mybucket/customer1/date'
    additional_settings => {
      force_path_style => true
      follow_redirects => false
                }
  }
}
```

Where do i go from here?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

```
input {
  s3 {
    access_key_id => "something"
    secret_access_key => "something_else"
    region => "some_region"
    bucket => "mybucket"
    interval => "10"
    sincedb_path => "/tmp/sincedb_something"
    backup_add_prefix =>'date-'
    backup_to_bucket => "mybucket"
    additional_settings => {
      force_path_style => true
      follow_redirects => false
                }
  }
}
```

You cannot use backup_add_prefix without backup_to_bucket, although their documentation suggests that. I hope that helps.